# Getting the URL from a submitted image

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, discord, discord.js

code with node.js and discord.js:

```
client.on('message', function(message){
  //  if (message.author.client) return;
    var Attachment = (message.attachments).array();
    console.log(Attachment); //outputs array
    console.log(Attachment.url); //undefined
    console.log(Attachment.MessageAttachment); //undefined
    console.log(Attachment.MessageAttachment['url']); //error
});
```

[output of "console.log(Attachment);"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE9JY.png)

how do i get the string from

```
[MessageAttachment
  {...,
   url: '..png',
   ...}
]
```

Comment: It should be `Attachment[0].url`. I am not much familiar with node or discord, but from the console output, it seems like `Attachment` is an array.

Comment: that worked, i'm not very familiar with array in JavaScript, thanks

Comment: You're welcome! I just posted an answer mentioning these details for any future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot of console, it looks like `Attachment` is an array, not an object. So, you would need to access the first element from that array and then the `url` property. Like this:

```
Attachment[0].url
```

Also, if there is a possibility of having multiple attachments, you could iterate over them using a `for` or `forEach` loop. Something like this:

```
Attachment.forEach(function(attachment) {
  console.log(attachment.url);
})
```